# First Generation ipod Shuffle does not automount in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, automount, ipod

I have a 1GB First Generation ipod Shuffle, thought it would be fun to see if it still works.
Have verified it is functioning on a Win/PC and a Mac and it plays music.
When I plug it in to my ubuntu laptop it will not mount.

System info;

HP-Compaq 6735b laptop
ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit (fully updated)
Memory: 2.7 GiB

I have installed gtkpod
`lsusb` shows

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 08ff:2810 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2810
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b059 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CKF7037 HP webcam
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 03f0:171d Hewlett-Packard Bluetooth 2.0 Interface [Broadcom BCM2045]
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ac:1300 Apple, Inc. iPod Shuffle
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You might need mtpfs

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Comment: Do i need to do further config or should this just work after install?

Comment: If that was the problem, it'll just work. Lots of mp3 players and phones don't get recognized as a "drive" and need this.